# Passing parameter to the method of an aspx page from Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, c#-4.0

Code I tried:

*Page1.aspx:*

id value is `2`

`location.href = "Page2.aspx/Method1";`

*Page2.aspx:*

```
public void Method1(string id)
{
}
```

I want to **pass** the parameter value - `id` which is `2` to the `Method1` in `Page2.aspx` from `Page1.aspx` using `Javascript`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that Method1 is declared in codebehind as below: ([more info](http://forums.asp.net/t/1895757.aspx?how+to+add+a+webmethod+attribute+into+a+function+in+an+aspx+file+of+vb+net))

```
[WebMethod]
public static void Method1(string id)
{
}
```

Have you tried this code?

```
location.href = "Page2.aspx/Method1?id=2";
```